# Landlord shut water off to force me to move

Tags: landlord

In process of moving but have been trying to come up with money to get water and electric. Landlord turned off water to force me to move. I can shower or clean anything or have water for pets. So stressed I can't sleep

Comment: Knowing your country would be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? You've just stated some facts without actually asking one.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there is a legal question, and not just a complaint: "Is it legal for a landlord to shut off the water, to force me to move"? There may be some country where this is legal, but generally, no. A landlord cannot force a tenant to move. At the end of the lease, they may terminate the lease; if the tenant does not move, the landlord has to follow a legal procedure to get a court order to evict the tenant. Likewise if the tenant has violated the lease, the landlord has to go to court. If you're in the middle of your lease and the landlord just doesn't like you anymore, he has to just suck it up until the lease terminates – thought here could be some local exceptions where he can terminate the lease because he is moving in to the unit to live there. Whatever the case, turning off the water, cutting off the electricity or gas, etc. are all illegal actions.

However, a landlord does not necessarily have an obligation to pay for your water. It might be part of the lease, and there are often local laws (esp. relating to the case where an apartment does not have a separate water meter). It's possible that they legally closed the account with the water company, and you have to open your own account – but again, they can't do this for the purpose of making life difficult and forcing you to leave.

Comment: I believe your missing a "not" in the first sentence of the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.